# Difference between quartz and quartz-jobs

Tags: quartz-scheduler, jobs, quartz

There are 2 dependencies for quartz. The dependency quartz(1st option below) has all the basic required classes needed for a basic job scheduling and execution. What is quartz-jobs used for?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

quartz-jobs.jar contains various optional Quartz job implementation classes that you can use in your application. There are jobs that can:

- invoke an EJB method
- run a native process (i.e. executable app/script)
- invoke a listener if a configured file's "last modified at" timestamp changes
- enqueue a JMS message in a configured JMS destination / topic
- invoke a JMX bean method
- send an SMTP message (email) to the configured recipient

For details, please refer to Quartz [javadoc](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.3.0) (check all classes in org.quartz.jobs package and sub-packages).